# LocalSessionFactoryBean packagesToScan not working with multiple values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I'm learning Hibernate and Spring. I've multiple entity classes. Below is directory structure of my project:
[image]

here `LoginUser` and `Student` are two entities annotated with `@Entity`. I've configured `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>


    </beans:bean>
```

With this configuration I'm able to persist `LoginUser` instance in database. But when I put multiple values for `packagesToScan` property, then it gives an exception **org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity.LoginUser**
Here is the configuration with multiple (array) values for `packagesToScan`

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:array>
                <beans:value>
                    com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>
                    com.sachin.onlineexam.student.entity
                </beans:value>
            </beans:array>

        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>
```

**PROBLEM:** When `packagesToScan` is configured with single package value as `<beans:property name="packagesToScan" value = "com.sachin.onlineexam.login.LoginUser/>` then my application works **FINE** and data is stored in database. But when it is configured with `<beans:array><beans:value>...</beans:value></beans:array>` or with `<beans:list>...</beans:list>` then the above `exception` is thrown. Providing more than one value inside `<beans:array></beans:array>` tag also **Not Work** and give same exception.

Is it the problem with `packagesToScan` property or something else?

**NOTE:** I'm using hibernate 4 version `4.2.11` and Spring 4 version `4.3.23`. I've also tried with hibernate 5 and spring 5, though not working.

Comment: Use modern java based configuration, not the old xml base d

Comment: But it should work for xml configuration too...

Comment: Just use a `,` separated value in `value` element. You are making things too complex. `value="com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity,com.sachin.onlineexam.student.entity". Spring will automatically convert this.

Comment: It worked..... You can give an answer so that I can credit you

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a `value-type` on the collection tag:

```
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:list value-type="java.lang.String">
            <beans:value>
                com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
```

or

```
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <beans:value>
                com.sachin.onlineexam.login.entity
            </beans:value>
        </beans:array>
    </beans:property>
```

Answer (score -2):

use as bellow

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.erp</value>
            <value>com.bea</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the code in the question, without the prefix. Apparently there are namespaces involved and `beans` isn't the default namespace.